# How to create WinForms application in MFC?

Tags: windows, winforms, datagridview, mfc

In my project, i can implement my WF controls using C++/CLI. But is there any other possible ways to use DataGridview in MFC application other than the following,

1. Using C++/CLI implementation,
2. Using COM Technology.

Please suggest me any ideas.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would say No.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is the problem with the ways you have? Waht would be simpler as using C++/CLI?